# How to get real-time notifications in Flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket, real-time-updates

I am new in Flutter, I have used web_socket_channel in my app. Now I want to get notifications when the app is not running. Keeping the app running in the background is not possible, so what do you recommend me to do?

So far I found them:

**Websocket Manager**- They claim to open socket connection in the background, but I couldn't find enough resources to find out. 
*https://pub.dev/packages/websocket_manager*

**Background Fetch** - Opens the app for a few seconds in the background periodically (15 minutes or more). I do not prefer this one actually :( .
*https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch*

Comment: Check out push notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging), it's easy to implement in android and got a bit of configurations to do in IOS but it's good.

Comment: I am using, Django in Back-end with Postgres, am I still able to use firebase_messaging?

Comment: yes of course you will just setup a listener to your main page's initState and the other process is up to you, you can use onMessage, onResume, and onLaunch. once implemented properly its good

Comment: make sure to connect your back office to firebase as well

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to implement it today:)

Comment: Qonvex620 hey I am facing almost the same problem as Orkhan. As you said to make sure to connect with firebase. I don't want to use firebase at all.I am using a sockeapi.Is there any solution for getting notifications with data even after my app is kiiled?

Comment: I have to implement notification using an APIs and I have tried firebase messaging but couldn't implement that. Any solutions or suggestions ?